# C помощью pip не могу установить библиотеку matplotlib для python3

Tags: python, linux, linux-mint, matplotlib, pip

```
    pip3 install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-2.0.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=1.5.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from matplotlib)
Installing collected packages: matplotlib
  Running setup.py install for matplotlib ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-canmfolo/matplotlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-6hlu9exx-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [2.0.0]
                    python: yes [3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23)  [GCC
                            5.4.0 20160609]]
                  platform: yes [linux]

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [version 1.12.0]
                       six: yes [using six version 1.10.0]
                  dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.6.0]
               functools32: yes [Not required]
              subprocess32: yes [Not required]
                      pytz: yes [using pytz version 2017.2]
                    cycler: yes [using cycler version 0.10.0]
                   tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                            WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                            install it after matplotlib.]
                 pyparsing: yes [using pyparsing version 2.2.0]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
                  freetype: yes [version 2.6.3]
                       png: yes [version 1.2.54]
                     qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                            found. Using local copy.]

    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
               sample_data: yes [installing]
                  toolkits: yes [installing]
                     tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
            toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                    macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                    qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]
                    qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
                   gtk3agg: yes [installing, version 3.9.18]
                 gtk3cairo: yes [installing, version 3.9.18]
                    gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                     tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                            Tk]
                     wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                       gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                       agg: yes [installing]
                     cairo: yes [installing, pycairo version 1.10.0]
                 windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

    OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                    dvipng: no
               ghostscript: yes [version 9.18]
                     latex: no
                   pdftops: yes [version 0.41.0]

    OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                      dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    copying lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/pdfcorefonts/Helvetica-BoldOblique.afm -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.5/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/pdfcorefonts
    UPDATING build/lib.linux-i686-3.5/matplotlib/_version.py
    set build/lib.linux-i686-3.5/matplotlib/_version.py to '2.0.0'
    running build_ext
    building 'matplotlib.ft2font' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-i686-3.5
    creating build/temp.linux-i686-3.5/src
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DFREETYPE_BUILD_TYPE=system -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_matplotlib_ft2font_ARRAY_API -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -I/home/roma/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I. -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c src/ft2font.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.5/src/ft2font.o
    In file included from src/ft2font.cpp:9:0:
    src/mplutils.h:31:20: fatal error: Python.h: Нет такого файла или каталога
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

ТУТ ВЫДАЕТ ОШИБКУ

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-canmfolo/matplotlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-6hlu9exx-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-canmfolo/matplotlib/
```

Поначалу он выдавал только первую строчку. Я погуглил, посоветовали установить разные библиотеки (или еще что-то) для форматов изображение. После этого длина ошибки стала еще больше.
Что не так?

Comment: python3-dev попробуйте установить.

Comment: Или ставьте из репозитория своего дистрибутива.

Comment: Как Вы pip устанавливали?

Comment: рекомендую научиться [гуглить](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21530768/5997596)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите в системную область поставить, то используйте менеджер пакетов для вашей системы, к примеру на Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python{,3}-matplotlib
```

---

Чтобы `pip install` не пытался компилировать без необходимости на вашей системе, можно ставить уже собранные дистрибутивы в wheel формате. Попробуйте установить `python3-wheel` системный пакет или ставьте в virtualenv, чтобы можно было бы обновить pip, wheel Питон-пакеты, не трогая системные версии (современный pip или wheel умеют ставить `.whl`-файлы):

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 ve  # create virtualenv in ./ve directory
$ . ve/bin/activate         # activate it
(ve) $ pip install -U pip wheel  # make sure pip, wheel are up-to-date
(ve) $ pip install matplotlib
```

В этом случае установка сводится к скачиванию `.whl` файла для вашей системы и распаковке его в нужные директории (как zip-архив) -- нет компиляции и необходимые зависимости автоматически устанавливаются.

Чтобы управлять множеством virtualenv окружений, [можно `virtualenvwrapper` использовать](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Чтобы попробовать различные python реализации (к примеру, чтобы тестировать ваш код на нескольких версиях/реализациях Питона с помощью [`tox`](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)), можно использовать [`pythonz`](http://saghul.github.io/pythonz/) или [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

---

Чтобы скомпилировать пакет с C зависимостями такой как matplotlib (к примеру, чтобы собрать версию из репозитория), необходимо самостоятельно зависимости для сборки поставить:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep python{,3}-matplotlib
(ve) $ pip install git+https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git -U
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное.
`sudo apt-get install python{,3}-matplotlib`
Это прокатило, библиотека работает. 

В чем смысл этой команды? Что это такое? `{,3}-`

Comment: @RomaRomin: это [brace expansion в bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion). Использовано, чтобы как для python 2 так и 3 поставить пакет, не дублируя имени

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день, для установки matplotlib используйте следующий набор команд:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev python3.5-tk tk-dev
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev g++
pip3 install --user matplotlib
```